# Is it possible create trigger on indexedDB?

Tags: javascript, triggers, indexeddb

I want to know if it is possible create trigger on **indexedDB**?

I searched something about that on "uncle" google but no luck. Someone knows?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use indexedDB? Try use this https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

Answer (score 5):

There is no concept of triggers in IndexedDB, however you can create a wrapper for the IndexeDB api which you can use to define "triggers".

Here is example of generic add object function:

```js
function AddObject(dbName, storeName, data, callback) {
  var request = indexedDB.open(dbName);
  request.onsuccess = function(e) {
    var db = e.target.result;
    var trans = db.transaction([storeName], "readwrite");
    var store = trans.objectStore(storeName);

    var request = store.put(data);

    trans.oncomplete = function(e) {
      //add the trigger code here
      console.log("Triggered on data entry");
      callback();
    };

    request.onerror = function(e) {
      console.log("Error Adding: ", e);
    };
  };
};
```